# How can I enable cperl syntax check on aquamacs?

Tags: emacs, cperl-mode

Check syntax is in cperl menu disabled. If I try `M-x cperl-check-syntax`, I got error message

> Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, mode-compile.

I found no hint on [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CPerlMode).

Comment: Please refer to [ask] - as it stands, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Sobrique -- the question is most certainly answerable by any Emacs user with moderate experience -- even by a hobbyist such as myself who is not a programmer. Within the library `cperl-mode.el` there is a variable called `cperl-tips`, which contains a doc-string that states in relevant part:  "*Note that to enable Compile choices in the menu you need to install mode-compile.el.*"  The function `cperl-check-syntax` throws an error because `mode-compile.el` has not yet been installed by the original poster.  So, track down that library and place it in the `load-path`.

Answer (score 1):

Install the library `mode-compile.el` by downloading it and placing it in the `load-path`:  https://github.com/emacsmirror/mode-compile/blob/master/mode-compile.el -- then, either evaluate the buffer of the newly added library or restart Aquamacs.

The interactive function `cperl-check-syntax` is looking for that library and throws an error when it cannot be found.  The doc-string for `cperl-tips` states in relevant part:  "*Note that to enable Compile choices in the menu you need to install `mode-compile.el`.*"